# check if each "key" in a dictionary matches a property of a model and map the dictionary's value (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

I have a dictionary called dataDump.

I have a model called model.

Ultimately, I want to map the values stored in dataDump to the properties of model. The dataDump's properties will change depending on the user's input, so I would like them to be mapped "smartly" rather than map each property manually.

I have the foundations of the code started but I'm not sure how to finish it.

```
//put the model's properties into an array.

Type type = model.GetType();

PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();



//loop through the array of model's properties.

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{

    //if the current property == a property in dataDump

    //model.property = the value of the matched dataDump property

}
```

Comment: What's the signature of `dataDump` ? `Dictionary<string, object>` ?

Comment: <string, string> sorry should have included this in the post

Comment: "Smart" things are dangerous in programming. I would advice you to not do such things unless you have I really good reason to do it. Instead I would foster the "boring & dump" way to match properties manually.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

```
//Assuming your dataDump is something like follows.
var dataDump = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dataDump.Add("Property1", "Value1");
dataDump.Add("Property2", "Value2");
dataDump.Add("Property3", "Value3");


Model m = new Model();
var properties = m.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(var p in properties){
    if (dataDump.Keys.Contains(p.Name)) { 
        var val = dataDump[p.Name];
        p.SetValue(m, val);
    }
}
 //These are for the verification purpose
Console.WriteLine(m.Property1);
Console.WriteLine(m.Property3);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Strategy here is this.

1. `dataDump.Keys.Contains(p.Name)` will return `true` if the name of the property `p` is contained in the dictionary `dataDump` as a key.
2. `var val = dataDump[p.Name]` extracts the value under `p.Name` in the dictionary `dataDump` and assign it to a temporary variable `val`. This is only for the sake of clarity. You can minify this.
3. `p.SetValue(m, val)` sets the value `val` for the property, named `p.Name` in the model object `m`.

**EDIT** Suggested by [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir)

```
foreach(var p in properties){
    string val;
    if (dataDump.TryGetValue(p.Name, out val)) { 
        p.SetValue(m, val);
    }
}
```

is even better. That avoids the double lookup in the `dataDump`.

**EDIT** Added for the completeness sake.

This could also be easily achieved using [Enumerable Methods for LInQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx), as follows. As you can see, it simplifies the code into a very brief expression, unlike previously.

```
var properties = m.GetType().GetProperties();
properties
    .Where(p => dataDump.Keys.Contains(p.Name)) // Finds the matching keys from the dictionary
    .ToList() // Converts the reduced array into a list
    .ForEach(x => x.SetValue(m, dataDump[x.Name])); // For each of the elements in the list, set the value of m from the dataDump
```

Comment: I would avoid the double lookup in the dictionary, once with `Contains` and again with `[]`: `if (dataDump.TryGetValue(p.Name, out var val)) p.SetValue(m, val);`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yup.. That's much better. I didn't know about `TryGetValue()`. :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir But we should know the types in the `dataDump` upfront for that isn't it? Isn't that a small downside?

Comment: Well that is determined by the dictionary anyway, you code only works for string properties, making it `Dictionary<string, object>` would be better, and we would get a runtime error if the types do not match. Or use some other conversion algorithm from string to p.PropertyType

Comment: Yup. That's true. Anyways I have taken the liberty of assuming the signature of the string.